Telegram Bot with Anonymous Answering
I wrote a Telegram bot where I can send directly questions from the bot to a group where I'm and several people are admins.
I made a button in the group itself with "Reply to this question". Sadly it doesn't work.
My question is if that is even possible to answer to a specific user while responding from a group. And maybe there is bot which can do that without showing the user id of the person who is asking the question.
Thanks
